# Different behavior while debugging than while running

Tags: c++, debugging, clion

I have problem with running and debugging my program.
The thing is that when I run my program by 'Run' there is some bug, but when I'm trying to debug it, then it works fine.
I don't have a clue how to solve that.
There is link for short video: [Video presenting problem](https://streamable.com/v05jpe)
While running 2 sectors don't work, while debugging everything works fine.
I'm using CLion.

I find that different behavior happens in this function(it's only a piece of code, because whole project is quite big):

```
LevelSegmentCords* Space::findPlaceForBruteForce(int x, int y, int z) {
    LevelSegmentCords *segmentCords = nullptr;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<this->getHeight();i++){
        int lastX=0,lastY=0;
        int checkerX=0,checkerY=0;
        do{
            segmentCords = levels[i].findFreeSector(x,y,lastX,lastY);
            if(segmentCords != nullptr){
                segmentCords->setStartLevel(i);
                for(int j=0;i+j<this->getHeight() && j<=z;j++){
                    if(!levels[i+j].isSectorFree(segmentCords->getX1(),
                                                 segmentCords->getY1(),
                                                 segmentCords->getX2()+1,
                                                 segmentCords->getY2()+1)){
                        checkerX = segmentCords->getX1();
                        checkerY = segmentCords->getY1();
                    }
                }
                if(checkerX != lastX || checkerY != lastY){
                    if(checkerX + 1 < this->x){
                        lastX = checkerX+1;
                        lastY = checkerY;
                    }else{
                        break;
                    }
                }else{
                    return segmentCords;
                }
            }else{
                break;
            }
        }while(true);
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

This function should basically find place to put there cuboid.

Comment: I suspect UB but it's hard to tell from the code you've shown. Have you identified on which line the difference starts to show? You could add some logging to be able to find that out in your release build.

Comment: I found the bug after logging all variables. Either way, that's realy interesting, that while debugging it was working fine before.

Comment: That's not that uncommon when you have UB - but can be tricky to find since it might look ok when running it in a debugger.